# Animation to display string lines by lines in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

I have a UITableView, and for each cell I need to display a string with line breaks inside. I want to display the text like a type writer BUT lines by lines:

- display a line.
- wait few seconds.
- display the second line.
- wait few seconds...

Example of String :

```
let myString="ipsum dolor sit amet \n consectetur adipiscing elit\n Vestibulum interdum felis arcu\n quis iaculis dolor malesuada ut"
```

Code:

```
class ViewController:UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate

    @IBOutlet var tableView : UITableView!
    var queue:OperationQueue!

    func configureCell(tableView: UITableView, cell: WithButtonsTableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {

        self.queue = OperationQueue()

        cell.dialogueLabel.setTextWriting(typedText: myString,callBackAfterCharacterInsertion: {
          self.tableView.beginUpdates()
           self.tableView.endUpdates()
        })

        cell.dialogueLabel.operation1.completionBlock = {
            //DO STUFF when all lines have been displayed
        }

    }
 }


//Custom class for UILabel in the cell 
class TypeWriterLabel: UILabel {

    var queue:OperationQueue!
    var operation1:BlockOperation! 

    func setTextWriting(typedText: String, callBackAfterCharacterInsertion:(()->())?) {

        text = ""
        let delimiter = "\n"
        let lines = typedText.components(separatedBy: delimiter)

        self.queue = OperationQueue()

         self.operation1 = BlockOperation(block: {

            for lineItem in lines {

                if self.queue != nil {

                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation({

                        self.text = self.text! + lineItem + "\n"
                        self.attributedText = self.setAttributedStyle()

                        callBackAfterCharacterInsertion?()

                    })
                }
            }
        })

        self.queue.addOperation(self.operation1)

    }
 }
```

With this code, all the text is displayed in one block, at one go.
I suppose I should add a delay time, between each lines break, so I tried to add an asyncAfter at many places, without success.

```
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { 

}
```

Comment: maybe this library can be a reference of the case you are looking for [https://github.com/wibosco/GhostTypewriter](https://github.com/wibosco/GhostTypewriter)

Comment: Thanks, It was useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I share my solution.

```
 func writingTextAnimation(dialogueLabelCell:UILabel, text:String, completion:@escaping ()->()) {

    let delimiter = "\n"
    var lines = text.components(separatedBy: delimiter)
    var index = 0

    animationTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: TYPING_TIME_INTERVAL, repeats: true, block: { (timer: Timer) in

        if index < lines.count {

            dialogueLabelCell.text =  dialogueLabelCell.text! + lines[index] + delimiter

            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.endUpdates()

            index = index + 1

        } else {
            self.animationTimer?.invalidate()
            self.animationTimer = nil
            completion()
        }

    })

}
```

Comment: Am I wrong or this `dialogueLabelCell.text =  dialogueLabelCell.text! + lines[index]` should be this `dialogueLabelCell.text =  dialogueLabelCell.text! + lines[index] + delimiter`?